# Kotlin multiplatform. What is StableRef lifetime?

Tags: c, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have C implementation for RedBlackTree and I want to store Kotlin objects in that tree. The question is: How to manage the lifetime of the objects and how does it work?

Here is my code for adding a pair to the tree

```
fun add(key: Key, value: Value) {
    val stableRef = StableRef.create(TreeMapEntry(key, value))
    c_rbinsert(nativeTree, stableRef.asCPointer())
}
```

`c_rbinsert` is C function which accepts void*.

I have several questions:

Is `TreeMapEntry` sent for the garbage collection here or is it somehow saved in StableRef?

Do I need to store a reference to `TreeMapEntry` somewhere else as well to stop it from being garbage collected?

Do I need to dispose the StableRef manually?

What are the best practices of managing the lifetime of a structure like that?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to store reference to `TreeMapEntry`; `StableRef.create` will create it for you and it won't be disposed by GC.

And yes, you have to dispose `StableRef` manually once you've done with it, using `StableRef#dispose()` method.